# I can't find .bash_profile

Tags: 10.10, command-line, bash

I am trying to learn how to tweak my shell in the file but can't seems to find the file in my home directory or in `/etc/profile`.

Is there any other file I need to search for, or am I expected to create one from scratch?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you open Nautilus, the file browser, go to your HOME directory and press CTRL+H you will see then all the hidden files (since hidden files start with the DOT `.` character). Since you are talking about the `.bash_profile`, I am guessing you want to start via console instead of an interactive desktop.

The difference between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` is the following:

- `.bashrc` is the one that you edit when you want to change the way xterm or gnome-terminal open the console. how the bash works in this interactive places.
- `.bash_profile` is the one you edit when you want to change how bash works when you login via console (Like the same way you login to a Ubuntu server or when you press CTRL+ALT+F1 to start a terminal)

Since `.bash_profile` does not come by default, you can just create it. But as I understand the default `.bash_profile` is now called `.profile` which can be seen in the HOME directory. Both, `.bashrc` and `.profile` can be edited to change how bash works in both, interactive and console modes.

NOTE: If by some way you create `.bash_profile`, then Ubuntu wont read `.profile` but instead go directly to `.bash_profile` since both of them are the same but `.bash_profile` has more compatibility because of old ways. So basically you do not need `.bash_profile` if you have `.profile`. So just remember:

`.bashrc - Interactive Console/Terminal (Gnome, KDE, Xfce...)`

`.profile - TTY Console/Terminal`

Comment: thx you are right i continude to read a little bit and found out that bash has a certain sequence it boots into first it tries to find .bash_profile if not found it tries to find .bash_login and if not found it tries to find .profile, and another thing i read is if you do create .bash_profile you can insert "source .profile"
command at the end of .bash_profile and it should execute .profile afterwards, but it's all from reading a book, so not sure how much it will work

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
man bash
```

and look at the INVOCATION section. That will explain how bash starts up.

Answer (score 1):

Look at .profile instead. I believe it loads that first then .bashrc.

.profile is loaded with each login. .bashrc is invoked with each subshell creation, including any subshells created within vi, emacs etc.