# I cannot find .bash_profile in ubuntu

Tags: bash, .profile

I can't find `.bash_profile` in Ubuntu 14.04 in my `/home/user` directory. I used the `ls -a` command to see the `.bash_profile`, but there isn't such a file.

Comment: You should use `~/.profile` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't find .bash\_profile](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16907/i-cant-find-bash-profile)

Comment: It's pretty common that some configuration file (or even directories) are missing. In that case the software that should read them will use a default configuration and/or read other sources to retrieve the configuration. If you want to modify a configuration file that doesn't exist simply create it first.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Ubuntu uses `~/.profile` .

you can create your `.bash_profile` in Ubuntu but then `.profile` will not be read.

If we read .profile content :

```
cat ~/.profile
```

## **output**

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
```

So use `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: .profile didn't work for me.
I had to edit .bashrc

`vim ~/.bashrc`
then
`. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Using .bash_profile does not work on Ubuntu. It uses Dash as a GUI login shell, not Bash, so bash_profile is not read.

Comment: If you edit your .profile, you need to log out and back in again to see the changes.

Answer (score 16):

When invoking a login shell bash will looks for its config files in this order:

```
[0] ~/.bash_profile
[1] ~/.bash_login
[2] ~/.profile
```

After finding the first one, it stops looking for the others so if there is a `.bash_profile` in my `$HOME` bash will not look for `.bash_login` and `.profile` anymore.

From these three file names, Ubuntu by default uses `.profile` you can rename it to `.bash_profile` if you like:

```
mv ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile
```

Now if we open a new bash shell using `bash -l`, `su - $USER`, `sudo -u $USER -i` or any other commands that runs bash as a login shell, `~/.bash_profile` will get sourced.

#### Important to note:

What I have talked about till now only applies to Bash itself, when you are logging into the system from a GUI, the display manager is responsible of sourcing the correct files.

Ubuntu uses `gdm3` as its display manager, if we take a look at: `/etc/gdm3/Xsession` we can see that none of the files will get sourced except: `.profile`:

```bsh
# First read /etc/profile and .profile
for file in /etc/profile "$HOME/.profile"; do
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    source_with_error_check "$file"
  fi
done
```

so if you are using a GUI to login, keep the file under `.profile` name otherwise you might miss some variables and settings in your environments.

I guess the better option is creating a symlink to `.profile`:

```
ln -s ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile
```

Now your data lives in `.profile`, `gdm` doesn't miss anything, bash loads `.bash_profile` which is actually `.profile`, and by editing each of them you get the same result.

#### Missing .profile?

If you don't have `.profile` then grab a copy of it  from here:

```
cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/.profile
```

or

```bsh
# Remember the note above
cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: But, if *Bash* is looking for ~/.bash_profile first, then how come it isn't doing this in Ubuntu? Has Ubuntu modified Bash? This seems strange. `man bash` on Ubuntu still describes how it will look for .bash_profile first.

Comment: It looks for `.bash_profile` **first** it can't find it (because it does not exists) then looks for `.bash_login` can't find it again (because Ubuntu does not uses these two name) finaly it looks for `.profile` and yes there it is. So if you create a `.bash_profile` in `~` then you are overwriting ubuntu's `~/.profile`, it's the default behavior of bash nothing has been modified here.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought at first, too! And what you describe DOES happen on RHEL. But on Ubuntu, it does not. If I create a `.bash_profile`, it is not read. I just realized that this is because Ubuntu no longer uses 'Bash' as a GUI login shell. It uses 'Dash' instead. I *think* this has been true since about 18.04.

Comment: You are missing the point here. Actually we are talking about the bash itself, what I'm saying here is that Ubuntu creats ’.profile’ and not the others,  so if we open a new bash shell (login shell) that's the order of reading these files, doesn't matter what distro we are using. :)

Comment: If readers rename .profile to .bash_profile as your answer suggests, then for people on Ubuntu, that file will not be read on login, nor on opening a terminal. You have broken their system. The only way that file will get read is if they launch bash sessions with the '--login' arg to explicitly make it a login shell. That will never happen automatically on their desktop.

Comment: @JonathanHartley You are both right and wrong, you are right about `.bash_profile` not being sourced while logging in from GUI but wrong about `dash` being used as login-shell, read [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) also removing `.profile` wouldn't broke the system... I'll investigate a little bit more and then I'll update my answer. thanks for pointing the issue out :)

Comment: @JonathanHartley Updated the answer ...

Comment: Good update. Nice work. I see what you say about Dash not being the login shell. I read otherwise elsewhere, and if Bash is the login shell then I don't understand why it doesn't source .bash_profile on login. But presumably I'm just confused about that somehow.

Comment: @JonathanHartley As I said, while using GUI, `gdm` is responsible of sourcing the config files and make environment ready, however you can press CTRL+ALT+F2 or any other "Fx" to go into a tty, then login using your credentials, now based on what is your default login shell (`getent passwd $USER | cut -f7 -d:`) that shell will be used as a login and interactive shell, if it's bash then `.bash_profile` will get sourced.

Comment: Yep yep, I realize all that.

Answer (score 5):

That means the file does not exist. But, you can create the file and `bash` executes/sources the file if `bash` is invoked as a login shell. So evertime you login via a shell (for example via `ssh`).

If you want the content to execute everytime you open a terminal, then you should modify the `.bashrc` file instead.

Comment: can you get some idea about why .bash_profile file is missing ?

Comment: You can copy it from `/etc/skel/` directory.

Comment: It's a design desicion of canonical. But, that does not mean cannot do it.

Comment: I explained the reason `.bash_profile` is missing (and does not work) on Ubuntu in comments on other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Top answer to use `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bash_profile` did not work for me.

Modifying `.bashrc` worked

Just:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Note: I'm using Ubuntu WSL.

Comment: In genuine Linux, the .profile is applied when you login to the GUI, or connect remotely, or log in to the console, ie after pressing ctrl+shift+F2. It's supposed to represent the initial time you login to the machine, creating a shell which is parent to all other processes you subsequently create. I suspect that on WSL, there is no such thing as any of this, so your .profile might never be read.

Comment: same for me. `~/.profile` just not loaded by default in ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the .bashrc you will find it in your home folder. If it isn't there, you can copy it from the /etc/skel folder to your home folder.

If you need some more information on this subject, please visit stefaan lippens page.

http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others