# Python path and Caffe path changes every few minutes

Tags: 16.04, python, environment-variables, caffe

Everyday I install caffe, it works, then I restart my the system and I get the error :

> ImportError: No module named caffe

So I fix it by

> import sys
>
> sys.path.append('/home/shubham/caffe/python')

And everything works (only until I exit my ipython) no matter what my `env` variables are upto.

On checking my `env` variables `CAFFE_ROOT` & `PYTHONPATH` are always stuck to this directory: `/home/shubham/Desktop/dir/vgg_face_caffe/` no matter how much I change them. Although python always seems to work even with the `PYTHONPATH` set to a directory where there is no python installation at all.

My questions are :

How do I fix up the caffe path so I don't get the import module error ?
Why do the environment variables not making sense ? That is, how is python working with the wrong `PYTHONPATH` path and yet caffe doesn't work when I set the right path ?
And why do they keep changing by itself ?

I am on ubuntu 16.04

Thank you for reading !

EDIT: just realized `PYTHONPATH` and `CAFE_ROOT` are always same as the directory in I am in. Still need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazing! Couldn't figure it out for days but 20mins after posting here, my brain works.

My ~/.profile was a mess. the `CAFFEROOT` env variable was set to `$(pwd)` and hence `PYTHONPATH` to `$(pwd)/python` .

Also, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510709/i-can-not-find-bash-profile-in-ubuntu) answer helped me figure out the mess about having to bash profiles.